# Why cout.put() doesn't work properly in stream?

Tags: c++

Why program results are diffentent in such 2 cases?

case 1)

```
cout<<"using cout.put(c): "<<cout.put(c);
cout.put('!');
```

case 2)

```
cout<<"using cout.put(c): ";
cout.put(c);
cout.put('!');
```

in case 1) is:
using cout.put(c): 0x477864!

in case 2) is:
using cout.put(c): U!

Answer (score 3):

To elaborate on what others have said: in case 1, the compiler
will try to find a `<<` operator for the return value of
`cout.put(c)`, and use it.  `cout.put(c)` returns
a `std::ostream&`, for which there is no `<<`, but an
`std::ostream` will convert implicitly to a `bool` (C++11) or
a `void*` (earlier C++).  So you call `<<` for a `void*`
(judging from your output).

Also note that when `cout.put(c)` is called  within the
expression is unspecified (except that it must be before the
`<<` for the `void*`).  So you could easily end up with either:

```
Uusing cout.put(c): 0x477864!
```

or

```
using cout.put(c): U0x477864!
```

(Because the `<<` are in fact function calls, which introduce
sequencing, I don't think any other combinations are possible.)

In general, anytime you have a sequence of `<<`, expect the
*value* of the right side to be output, regardless of any side
effects the expression might have.  You call `cout.put(c)` for
its side effects, not its value, so you shouldn't use it in
a `<<`.  (To output a single character in the sequence, just use
`<< c`.)

Comment: My answer was obsolete now you wrote yours, so deleted it and `+1` this instead.

Answer (score 1):

`cout.put(c)` returns a reference to the `cout` object. In the first case you print that object.

[std::basic_ostream::put reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/put)